# SOAP error when calling remote service

Tags: soap, symfony-1.4

My webservice was created using plugin: http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/ckWebServicePlugin provided for Symfony 1.4

It worked fine on local machine but giving me error when I deploy service to remote server.

This is stack trace:

> The server sent HTTP status code 200: OK Stack Trace 
>   com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.createResponsePacket(HttpTransportPipe.java:277)
>   com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.process(HttpTransportPipe.java:228)
>   com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.processRequest(HttpTransportPipe.java:143)
>   com.sun.xml.ws.transport.DeferredTransportPipe.processRequest(DeferredTransportPipe.java:110)
>   com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:961)
>   com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:910)
>   com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:873)
>   com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:775)
>   com.sun.xml.ws.client.Stub.process(Stub.java:429)
>   com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.doProcess(SEIStub.java:168)
>   com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:119)
>   com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:102)
>   com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:151)
>   com.sun.proxy.$Proxy149.restaurantVerificationDetails(Unknown Source)
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
>   org.netbeans.modules.websvc.manager.ui.ReflectionHelper.callMethodWithParams(ReflectionHelper.java:772)
>   org.netbeans.modules.websvc.manager.ui.TestWebServiceMethodDlg$MethodTask.run(TestWebServiceMethodDlg.java:744)
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: were you able to figure this out. I am seeing the exact same problem. please share if you have a solution