# javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException timeout from soap request using jax-ws

Tags: web-services, soap, jenkins, jax-ws

I am getting the following exception when I run my build in `jenkins`.

Here is what I did

1. I created java files from running the following command
   `wsimport -keep -verbose http://foobar.com/ws/server?wsdl`
2. I copied the files created to my project and used it to construct the client stubs
3. Here is how my client looks

   ```
   public class SoapClient {

      private ServiceSoap soapService;

       //30 secs
       private static final Integer REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MILLI = 90000;
       //15 secs
       private static final Integer CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLI  = 90000;

       public SoapClient(){
           Service service = new Service();
           service.setHandlerResolver(new JaxWsHandlerResolver());
           soapService = service.getServiceSoap();
           ((BindingProvider)soapService).getRequestContext()
          .put(BindingProviderProperties.REQUEST_TIMEOUT,REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MILLI);
           ((BindingProvider)soapService).getRequestContext()
                   .put(BindingProviderProperties.CONNECT_TIMEOUT,CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLI);
       }

       public SoapResponse processRequest(String refNum){
           SoapResponse response = null;
           try {
              response = soapService.requestInfo(refNum); 
           }
           catch (Exception ex){
               LOG.error("error connecting to Soap service, {}",ex.getLocalizedMessage());
               LOG.error(ex.getMessage());
               LOG.error(ex.getCause().toString());
               ex.printStackTrace();

           }
           return response;
       }
   ```

   }
4. I have set connection and request timeouts above. I have increased upto 10 minutes. till I see the same exception. I have included the jaxws-rt dependency in my pom.xml

Here it is

```
      <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
            <jaxws.version>2.2.10</jaxws.version>
        </dependency>
```

Here is the exception I am seeing

```
2016-05-05 04:43:40,337 [main] ERROR foo.bar.foobar.client.SoapClient - java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpClientTransport.readResponseCodeAndMessage(HttpClientTransport.java:210)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.createResponsePacket(HttpTransportPipe.java:241)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.process(HttpTransportPipe.java:232)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.processRequest(HttpTransportPipe.java:145)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.DeferredTransportPipe.processRequest(DeferredTransportPipe.java:110)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:1136)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:1050)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:1019)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:877)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.Stub.process(Stub.java:463)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.doProcess(SEIStub.java:191)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:108)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:92)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:161)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy50.requestInfo(Unknown Source)
    at
```

The exception seems to be `sun` related. I have read other posts. but none helped me actually. I am stuck here for two days and any help here would be much appreciated.

Thanks

**EDIT**
I pretty much see same issue as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32444900/soap-error-when-calling-remote-service). but no solution has been posted

Comment: 1) Is the remote service reachable from the machine running this SoapClient app (eg `telnet foobar.com 80` works), and 2) Your timeout values here are 90 seconds; how long is the application taking to print this error? 3) can you independently verify (with a tool like curl or soapui) the remote service is responding?

Comment: @scotth: the remote service is responding. telnet works. it prints the errors just after the timeout of 90 secs. I am pretty confident remote service is responding. There is a status page which I could curl and it responds fine

Comment: Ok. But are you performing this `curl` from the same computer / server as the one that is running `SoapClient` app? Assuming yes, we can assume the socket timeout is not firewall or connectivity related. Next step would be to try the actual service operation outside of your app, not just a status page. The remote service/server may be up, but `requestInfo()` may be very slow. Try invoking the remote service with a tool like SoapUI or an IDE test harness and see if you experience 90+ sec response times.